# Managing Free and a Trial / Paid in the same code base in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I've got a free ad supported game on the market place. I'd like to add a paid version which will have the same ads in trial mode.

Will the IsTrial method return false in the free version? Is there any other way to distinguish between the two versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Free versions will have IsTrial=false - they are essentially purchased for $0

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this : http://invokeit.wordpress.com/2011/09/20/free-trial-and-paid-apps/